# Is onCreateView() event fired every time we create a new Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager which has 5 pages.
In the `getView()` method in the Adapter of this ViewPager I wrote:

```
MyFragment fragment =new MyFragment(myObject, context);
return fragment;
```

Now, it works correctly.
But, in a particular situation, the `onCreateView()` event of MyFragment is not fired.

When I debug my code it goes to the Fragment constructor, but it does not enter the `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: Which Viewpager adapter are you using FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating a fragment doesn't invoke its lifecycle callbacks, these methods will be called only after you commit the fragment transaction, e.g.:

```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(myObject, context);
  transaction.add(fragment , "some_tag");
  transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.How can I return the fragment in this case?

Comment: I don't understand why does it change you returning the fragment, can you maybe explain a bit more?

Comment: I used a fragmentpageradapter and I want to return the fragment in getview method.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment's `OnCreateView` method is called once when the fragment is created for the first time. But when you swipe through your `ViewPager`, the fragment is **hidden**, not **destroyed**. So when you swipe back to your fragment, `onCreateView` is not called because the fragment is **already created**.